# What is the best practice to aggregate substrings in string values with python?

Tags: python, string, count, sequence, aggregation

I have a very specific problem to solve. I have a DataFrame with strings (path) and associated metrics. To make the results more readable, I want to aggregate the paths in the strings (Count) under conditions. As soon as a substring occurs more often than once directly one after the other, a multiplier or something similar should be added to the substring at this point.

Example Input:
'SEO > direct_&c_(notset) > direct_&c_(notset) > direct_&c_(notset) > SEO'

Desired Output:
'SEO > 3 x (direct_&c_(notset)) > SEO'

As you can see the substring "SEO" should not be aggregated because order matters. The Input shows an User Path therefore important informations would getting lost if one would simple count the different substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to find matching adjacent components; this returns them grouped, so you can then use [`more_itertools.ilen` ("iterator length")](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.ilen) to get the count in each group (which will be 1 if there's no match).

```
from itertools import groupby

from more_itertools import ilen

in_str =  'SEO > direct_&c_(notset) > direct_&c_(notset) > direct_&c_(notset) > SEO'

out_list = []
for component, group in groupby(in_str.split(' > ')):
    count = ilen(group)
    if count == 1:
        out_list.append(component)
    else:
        out_list.append('%s x (%s)' % (count, component))

out_str = ' > '.join(out_list)
print(out_str)
```

If you don't want to use the `more_itertools` library, you can instead write:

```
count = sum(1 for _ in group)
```

This does the same thing as `ilen` but is rather more confusing to read.

Comment: Thank you very much dear kind Sir! The answer was exactly what I was looking for.